# How to display feh fullscreen slideshow on second screen

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspbian

I am running a Raspberry Pi 4 as a signage computer and I need to run slideshows on two televisions which both need to be able to fullscreen.

When I use [feh](https://feh.finalrewind.org) and attempt to fullscreen the screen2 it just fullscreens on screen1. I have tried the `--geometry` and it does not correct this without removing the fullscreen argument.

When I run `xrandr` it shows both screens as being screen 0: How can I make the Pi recognize the other screen as seperate from the original or is there some other image program that I can use other then feh for this?

```
#! /bin/bash

export DISPLAY=:0

feh --geometry 1920+1920 -xFZD 7.0
```

I have tried changing the display variable and swapping the positions of the `--geometry` and `-xFZD` to no avail thinking perhaps they execute in order but the full screen seems to supersede anything I try to do to move it to the second screen and without the full screen the image does not fit the screen properly.

Answer (score 1):

I was just looking to do the same and found that I can utilize various monitors in my setup by adding the `--xinerama-index {screen_index}` flag.

example

```
feh --geometry 1920+1920 -xFZD 7.0 --xinerama-index 0
feh --geometry 1920+1920 -xFZD 7.0 --xinerama-index 1
```